# Border (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to put the widgets inside the mobile so that the picture is like a border, I want to put the widget inside the mobile frame, how can I do that?

[image]

Code:

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: MobileImage(),
        ),
        child: Widgets(),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code & I have added a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHBFa.jpg) also for your favor.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 0.9,
          heightFactor: 0.9,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/iphone13.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Container(),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                  widthFactor: 0.8,
                  heightFactor: 0.9,
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text('Text ${index+1}'),
                        );
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return const SizedBox(height:10);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

}
```

N.B: Here, `"assets/images/iphone13.png"` are the iPhone background image.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this,

```
 Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: //your border,
      image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage(MobileImage()))

    ),
   child: Widgets(),
  ),
```

and also u can use the **stack** widget to Put The Widgets Inside the border Image